# How to add a datepicker to bootstrap page?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a popup calender, but it is not working as i expected.
I need some help to add a datetimepicker code for bootstrap.

The following code contains a simple *Hello World*, as well as the datetimepicker textbox, but not the picker.

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>`enter code here`
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="css/one-page-wonder.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="../css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
            <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dtp_input1" class="col-md-2 control-label">DateTime Picking</label>
            <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="1979-09-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
                <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" /><br/>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
                //language:  'fr',
                weekStart: 1,
                todayBtn:  1,
                autoclose: 1,
                todayHighlight: 1,
                startView: 2,
                forceParse: 0,
                showMeridian: 1
            });

            $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
                language:  'fr',
                weekStart: 1,
                todayBtn:  1,
                autoclose: 1,
                todayHighlight: 1,
                startView: 2,
                minView: 2,
                forceParse: 0
            });

            $('.form_time').datetimepicker({
                language:  'fr',
                weekStart: 1,
                todayBtn:  1,
                autoclose: 1,
                todayHighlight: 1,
                startView: 1,
                minView: 0,
                maxView: 1,
                forceParse: 0
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check .. all the neccessary files are loaded properly via Firebug ?

Comment: How meany css and js folders do you have? Check the console and make sure everything is loaded properly.

Answer (score 3):

I am using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
 library for bootstrap.
Please check source code below. It is very simple.

You just need to make sure that you have added required libraries and in correct order. 
You don't need to have local libraries for this you can use any CDN provider, like I am using cdnjs.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```